# Detecting UTF-8 in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, regex, unicode, utf-8

I have this method in C#:

```cs
public static int HasUniCodeCharacter(string text)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(Regex.IsMatch(text, "[^\u0000-\u00ff]"));
}
```

I want know, If I want have a function in SQL for doing this method job, How I should write this?

Comment: `string text` is in UTF-16. The presence of Unicode codepoints other than those in the range of u0000-u00ff has nothing to do with detection of UTF-8. Please see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert the string using one of non unicode collations in sql to see if returns the same tsring or not and that is how you can find out if it was a unicode string or not.

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsUnicode (@string AS NVARCHAR(500))
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN (CASE WHEN CAST(@string AS VARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = @string THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
END
```

Comment: This nicely shows that what the OP [actually meant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) is to know *whether a string is representable in a certain encoding* (Latin1 in this case). This is *not* the same as `IsUnicode`.